# Least Angle regression coefficient reaches zero after included

Tags: regression, least-squares, lasso

In LARS how is it possible that after including a variable it could reach zero again?
http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~isbell/reading/papers/lasso_simple.html.pdf

I understood that it works like:
1) choose the ariable more correlated with y
2) start increasing the parameter of that value until the correlation of this variable and the residual of that regression is equal to the correlation of a 2nd variable and the same residual.
3)start increasing the value of the 2nd variable and the 1st one (at the same time, I guess each one in the original direction(?)) until the correlation... (same as 2)

Now, How is it possible that a varible coefficient rechaes again zero? Is it because it chages the direction once it's "joined" with the previous variables entered in the regression?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to compute the lasso a modified version of the Lars algorithm is used.

If a certain condition does not hold a variable can be removed by the set of active variables.

This is explained on pag 417 of this paper http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.aos/1083178935